# Putting "new venture" on resume

Tags: resume

I have been working on my own business idea for the past year, however, no accomplished product yet. How should I put it in my resume? Thanks.

Comment: Is the question how do I list a self employed position on my resume or is there something else you are trying to address?  If so that is not clear from the question

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest

> Your Own Company Name 01/2013 - 12/2013
>
> Developer
>
> Brief description of the product and experience

I am not sure what kind of product you were making. You can replace Developer by whatever is appropriate. During the interview, briefly explain it is your own business and you were doing it for yourself.

Don't hide it because it is an employment gap you need to explain. Don't emphasize it because the interviewer may not like the fact you were running your own business and failed to deliver.

However, the experience you gained during the past year is worth noting. Lessons learned are valuable.

Comment: I would be a bit nervous about someone who had a year-long gap in employment and didn't actually manage to ship anything afterwards personally. Not that anything will make the gap look nice in this case, but I think this has the best chance for success. Note that you will likely be asked specifically about why you didn7t ship.

Answer (score -3):

Don't.  You may be perceived as a risk by a potential employer.  Employers want somebody "hungry" and with limited choices, not someone potentially distracted.

Comment: Well, they would like to know what I have been doing for the past year, wouldn't they?

Comment: I would persuade you to downplay, severely, the fact that it was YOUR business opportunity.

Comment: A year long gap in your resume is a bigger red flag to me than pursuing your own business idea.

Comment: *Employers want somebody "hungry" and with limited choices, not someone potentially distracted.* - If you are dealing with this type of employer regularly then you are scraping the bottom of the barrel... I would consider looking at other career options